# nested awk commands?

Tags: awk

I have got following two codes:

```
nut=`awk "/$1/{getline; print}" ids_lengths.txt`
```

and

```
grep -v '#' neco.txt |
grep -v 'seq-name' |
grep -E '(\S+\s+){13}\bAC(.)+CA\b' |
awk '$6 >= 49 { print }' |
awk '$6 <= 180 { print }' |
awk '$4 > 1 { print }' |
awk '$5 < $nut { print }' |
wc -l
```

I would like my script to replace "nut" at this place:

```
awk '$4 < $nut { print }'
```

with the number returned from this:

```
nut=`awk "/$1/{getline; print}" ids_lengths.txt`
```

However, $1 in code just above should represent not column from ids_lengths.txt, but first column from neco.txt! (similiarly as I use $6 and $4 in main code).

A help how to solve these nested awks will definitely be appreciated:-)

---

edit:
Line of my input file (neco.txt) looks like this:

```
FZWTUY402JKYFZ  2   100.000 3   11  9     4.500 7   0   0   0   .   TG  TGTGTGTGT
```

The biggest problem is that I want to filter those lines that have in the fifth column number less than number, which I get from another file (ids_lengths.txt), when searching with first column (e.g. FZWTUY402JKYFZ). That's why I put "nut" variable in my draft script :-)

ids_lengths.txt looks like this:

```
>FZWTUY402JKYFZ 
153
>FZWTUY402JXI9S 
42
>FZWTUY402JMZO4 
158
```

Comment: There's almost certainly no need to pipe all those `grep`s and `awk`s and to try to nest `awk`s. Please show some input data and your desired output data and we'll help you simplify all that.

Comment: Agree with *Dennis Williamson*. I'm pretty sure that all stuff can be done with an `awk` script without all those pipes.

Comment: You need the `$nut` invocation of `awk` using double quotes; otherwise, `awk` interprets `$nut` as `$0` (because its variable `nut` is zero).  (Or, use `awk -v nut=$nut '$4 < nut { print }'`, avoiding the problem @DennisWilliamson pointed out.)  The key point is that the shell does not expand `$nut` inside single quotes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: In that case the `$4` would need to be `\$4`.

Comment: My `grep -E` doesn't understand `\S` or `\s`, but my `grep -P` does.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine the two `grep -v` operations and the four consecutive `awk` operations into one of each.  This gives you useful economy without completely rewriting everything:

```
nut=`awk "/$1/{getline; print}" ids_lengths.txt`
grep -E -v '#|seq-name' neco.txt |
grep -E '(\S+\s+){13}\bAC(.)+CA\b' |
awk -vnut="$nut" '$6 >= 49 && $6 <= 180 && $4 > 1 && $5 < nut { print }' |
wc -l
```

I would not bother to make a single `awk` script determine the value of `nut` and do the value-based filtering.  It can be done, but it complicates things unnecessarily — unless you can demonstrate that the whole thing is a bottleneck for the performance of the production system, in which case you do work harder (though I'd probably use Perl in that case; it can do the whole lot in one command).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I may use your script wrong way, but I guess I am close Perlnika:~$ nut=`awk "/$1/{getline; print}" ids_lengths.txt`; grep -E -v '#|seq-name' neco.txt | grep -E '(\S+\s+){13}\bAC(.)+CA\b' | awk -vnut=$nut '$6 >= 49 && $6 <= 180 && $4 > 1 && $5 < nut { print }' | wc -l
awk: cannot open 158 (No such file or directory)
0

Comment: @Perlnika: Perhaps quoting `-v nut="$nut"`? (This should always be done for AWK variable passing.)

Comment: Since the 158 should be the value of `nut`, there must be a space or something at the start of `$nut` that throws everything off.  So, quoting it should work: `awk -vnut="$nut" ...`.  But it isn't obvious how the space got there (unless you left a space in your typing).  You could do `echo "<<$nut>>"` and there should be no spaces.

Comment: You are right. 158 is really value of nut (third sequence in ids_lengths.txt and fifth line in neco.txt). Adding "" helped, but unfortunately resulted in -bash: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long. (if its important, ids_lengths has 561908 lines)

Comment: OK — the problem is that everyone assumed that `nut` would contain a single number.  You should consider doing an `exit` after printing the first matching value when determining `nut`.  Or you have to do some serious reworking of how that value is determined (sort in ascending order and choose largest, or smallest; or something).  The condition in the `awk` script implies `nut` is a single value — make sure it is just a single value.

Comment: It indeed is single value. You can be sure about that. As an bash beginner, I probably put "<<$nut>>" on wrong place. Here is code showing that it is one value:  nut=`awk "/FZWTUY402JKYFZ/{getline; print}" ids_lengths.txt`; echo $nut
153

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the script is using `$1`, and in your shell, `$1` is empty, so the pattern is empty, so every line matches? Something along those lines.  You can give your shell a value in `$1` with `set -- FZWTUY402JKYFZ`.  Then the code I wrote stands a chance of working.  If you paste the code into a shell file, you can then run it with `sh -x filename.sh FZWTUY402JKYFZ`, which is probably easier in the long run.  You can also revise the script to check that there is a `$1` and that it is vaguely appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Approximately:

```
awk -v select="$1" '$0 ~ select && FNR == NR { getline; nut = $0; } FNR == NR {next} $4 > 1 $5 < nut && $6 >= 49 && $6 <= 180 && ! /#/ && ! /seq-name/ && $NF ~ /^AC.+CA$/ {count++} END {print count}' neco.txt ids_lengths.txt
```

The regex will need to be adjusted to something that AWK understands. I can't see how the regex matches the sample data you provided. Part of the solution may be to use a field count as one of the conditions. Perhaps `NF == 13` or `NF >= 13`.

Here's the script above broken out on multiple lines for readability:

```
awk -v select="$1" '
    $0 ~ select && FNR == NR {
        getline
        nut = $0; 
    }
    FNR == NR {next}
    $4 > 1
    $5 < nut && 
    $6 >= 49 && 
    $6 <= 180 && 
    ! /#/ && 
    ! /seq-name/ &&
    $NF ~ /^AC.+CA$/ {
        count++
    } 
    END {
        print count
}' ids_lengths.txt neco.txt
```

Comment: the complicated regex should just match the last column and search for specific beginning and ends of sequence. For example those starting with AC and ending with CA. Then, length ($6) should be greater or equal than 49 and less or equal than 180, start ($4) should be greater than one, end ($5) less than "nut".

Comment: @Perlnika: I think I've fixed those issues.

Comment: Thanks. I probably made some typo when deleting spaces, will try to fix it.  awk -v select="$1" '$0 ~ select && FNR == NR {getline nut = $0; } FNR == NR {next} $4 > 1 $5 < nut && $6 >= 49 && $6 <= 180 && ! /#/ && ! /seq-name/ && $NF ~ /^AC.+CA$/ {count++} END {print count}' ids_lengths.txt neco.txt
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near =

Comment: @Perlnika: The oneliner version in my answer has a semicolon after `getline`. The version in your comment does not. That is where the syntax error is coming from.