# use one awk command to search for a string within a matching string

Tags: awk

I want to use awk to search for a string within a matching string. But the awk [guides](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/An_Awk_Primer/Search_Patterns_%281%29) and [examples](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/158891-awk-multiple-line-search-replace-one-liner.html) I've found only employ one match, or [promising sounding SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570253/nested-awk-commands) have answers so [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206418/how-to-use-awk-to-search-for-a-complete-match-of-text-within-one-column-of-a-csv) that I can't easily draw general principals from them to solve my issue.

For example, I want to get the event handler number for the "Thinkpad Extra Buttons" device from a `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` command with text like this:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab54
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=17aa Product=5054 Version=4101
N: Name="ThinkPad Extra Buttons"
P: Phys=thinkpad_acpi/input0
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event7 
B: KEY=18040000 0 10000000000000 0 101501b00102004 8000000001104000 e000000000000 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04f2 Product=b2ea Version=0518
N: Name="Integrated Camera"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/button
```

To produce output that looks something like

```
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event7
```

Using [record range patterns](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_9.html#SEC92) I can grab out just the "Thinkpad Extra Buttons" block, but then trying to add another search pattern like this:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices | awk '/Think/,/event/ {print}; /event/ {print $2}
```

I get all the unrelated Handlers lines, not just the one for "Thinkpad Extra Buttons"

```
Handlers=event0
Handlers=kbd
Handlers=kbd
Handlers=sysrq
N: Name="ThinkPad Extra Buttons"
P: Phys=thinkpad_acpi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event7 
Handlers=rfkill
Handlers=kbd
Handlers=event9
Handlers=event10
```

I realize I could pipe the results of that range pattern into a separate awk command and search on the H: Handlers line. However that doesn't work when I want to find multiple Thinkpad named devices, but really it seems like awk should be able to do this kind of thing and it bugs me that I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Don't ever use 'record range patterns'. They make solving trivial problems slightly briefer but can't be built upon for even slightly non-trivial problems like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the above answers work, but it kept biting at me that there should be a super short way to do this.

This is what I came up with:

```
awk '/Think/,/event/ {if(/event/) {print $4}}' /proc/bus/input/devices
```

The principal behind this is that it matches on a range, then within the first set of curly braces I can do line by line processing on those captured lines.

Answer (score 6):

This kind of problem lends itself well to paragraph-wise processing, rather then line-wise.
With GNU awk:

```
gawk -v RS='' '
    /N:.*ThinkPad Extra Buttons/ {
        match($0, /(H:.*event[0-9]+)/, a)
        print a[0]
        exit
    }
' /proc/bus/input/devices
```

If you're willing to stretch beyond awk:

```
perl -00 -lne 'if (/^N: Name=.ThinkPad Extra Buttons/m) {print /^(H:.*)$/m; exit}' /proc/bus/input/devices
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  What's the idea behind the -v RS part?

Comment: The awk variable RS is the record separator. By default it's `\n` so you each line is a record. Setting it to the empty string allows you to slurp blank-line-separated paragraphs as records. See the GNU awk manual for [Records](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Records.html#Records) and [Multi-line records](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html#Multiple-Line)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick solution that may work for you:

```
awk '
/^N: Name="ThinkPad Extra Buttons"$/ { found = 1; }
/^H: Handlers=/ { handlers = $0; }
$0 == "" { endRecord(); }
END { endRecord(); }
function endRecord() {
    if (found) {
        print handlers;
        found = 0;
    }
}
' file.txt
```

What this is doing is:

- looking for that "ThinkPad" line exactly, using it to flag that you're looking at a record that you care about.
- noting the contents of all "H" handler lines.
- printing out handler lines at the end of each "record", where each "record" is separated by a blank line. (NB: This isn't an Awk record; as far as Awk is concerned each line is a record.)

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation of what you are doing there.  I'll keep that technique in my bag of awk tricks

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve like below ....
1) Lets suppose i have below sorted output from where i needed it to be processed with awk .

```
$ grep mouse /proc/bus/input/devices
N: Name="Macintosh mouse button emulation"
H: Handlers=mouse0 event1
H: Handlers=mouse1 event3




   $ awk '/Macintosh /,/event/ {if(/event/) {print $2,$3}}' /proc/bus/input/devices
    Handlers=mouse0 event1
```

Below does not works for me...

```
$ awk '/Macintosh /,/event/ {if(/event/) {print $4}}' /proc/bus/input/devices
```

Comment: Sure, that makes sense- in the Thinkpad example text above there are four entities on the line, and on the mac example you use there are only 3.

Comment: Also, since you're new here I recommend reading this community guideline regarding comments being posted as answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette